# VoiceflowとMake間のAPI連携におけるUnauthorizedエラー

Tags: webapi

VoiceflowからMakeのWebhookへGETリクエストを送った際に、"Unauthorized"のエラーが発生するします。解決方法を教えてください。

- 作成中のもの：AlexaからchatGPTを呼び出すシステム
- 参考動画：https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLYF6ggdBfA
- エラー対象；[Make](https://www.make.com/en), [Voicefolow](https://www.voiceflow.com/)

[image: Make側の設定]

[image: Voiceflow側の設定 Certificateには何も入力していません]

[image: エラーメッセージ（Voiceflow）]